# DDD how to model time tracking?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am developing an application that has employee time tracking module. When employee starts working (e.g. at some abstract machine), we need to save information about him working. Each day lots of employees work at lots of machines and they switch between them. When they start working, they notify the system that they have started working. When they finish working - they notify the system about it as well.

I have an aggregate `Machine` and an aggregate `Employee`. These two are aggregate roots with their own behavior. Now I need a way to build *reports* for any given `Employee` or any given `Machine` for any given period of time. For example, I want to see which *machines* did given *employee* used over period of time and for how long. Or I want to see which *employees* worked at this given *machine* for how long over period of time.

Ideally (I think) my aggregate `Machine` should have methods `startWorking(Employee employee)` and `finishWorking(Employee employee)`.

I created another aggregate: `EmployeeWorkTime` that stores information about `Machine`, `Employee` and `start,finish` timestamps. Now I need a way to modify one aggregate and create another at the same time (or ideally some another approach since this way it's somewhat difficult).

Also, employees have a `Shift` that describes for how many hours a day they must work. The information from a `Shift` should be saved in `EmployeeWorkTime` aggregate in order to be consistent in a case when `Shift` has been changed for given `Employee`.

## Rephrased question

I have a `Machine`, I have an `Employee`. HOW the heck can I save information:

*This `Employee` worked at this `Machine` from 1.05.2017 15:00 to 1.05.1017 18:31.*

I could do this simply using CRUD, saving multiple aggregates in one transaction, going database-first. But I want to use DDD methods to be able to manage complexity since the overall domain is pretty complex.

Comment: If event sourcing is applicable there, how can I store domain events efficiently to build reports faster? Should each important domain event be its own aggregate? I also don't need to restore an aggregate from events since these events would be useless for aggregate construction.

Comment: What are the invariants that your aggregates must protect?

Comment: Multiple employees can't use the same machine at the same time. Multiple machines can't be used by the same employee at the same time. Employee must notify about finishing his work at given machine before starting another one at the other machine.

Comment: @EwanCoder I think these invariants are superficial. You risk running into cases like "Employee A starts to work on machine and goes in lunch without indicating he finished. Employee B can't use the machine given it's locked by Employee A.". I'd just allow them to record whatever they want and have them fix their inconsistent timesheet afterwards. You could also be smarter about it so that only self-inconsistencies must be fixed by a given employee before he starts using a new machine.

Comment: For instance Employee B would be allowed to use the machine anyway, but when A comes back and try to use another machine he's asked when he finished working on the previous one. The time entered (manual) would have to be before Employee B started to work on the machine. Something else you could do is to have auto-finish timers on machines that were not used for a few seconds/minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing an application that has employee time tracking module. When employee starts working (e.g. at some abstract machine), we need to save information about him working. Each day lots of employees work at lots of machines and they switch between them. When they start working, they notify the system that they have started working. When they finish working - they notify the system about it as well.

A critical thing to notice here is that the activity you are tracking is happening in the real world.  Your model is *not* the book of record; the world is.

`Employee` and `Machine` are real world things, so they probably aren't aggregates.  `TimeSheet` and `ServiceLog` might be; these are the aggregates (documents) that you are building by observing the activity in the real world.

> If event sourcing is applicable there, how can I store domain events efficiently to build reports faster? Should each important domain event be its own aggregate?

Fundamentally, yes -- your event stream is going to be the activity that you observe.  Technically, you could call it an aggregate, but its a pretty anemic one; easier to just think of it as a database, or a log.

In this case, it's probably just full of events like

```
TaskStarted {badgeId, machineId, time}
TaskFinished {badgeId, machineId, time}
```

Having recorded these events, you forward them to the domain model.  For instance, you would take all of the events with Bob's badgeId and dispatch them to his Timesheet, which starts trying to work out how long he was at each work station.

> Given that Machine and Employee are aggregate roots (they have their own invariants and business logic in a complex net of interrelations, timeshift-feature is only one of the modules)

You are likely to get yourself into trouble if you assume that your digital model controls a real world entity.  [Digital shopping carts and real world shopping carts](http://cascadefaliure.blogspot.com/2016/04/shopping-carts-and-book-of-record.html) are not the same thing; the domain model running on my phone can't throw things out of my physical cart when I exceed my budget.  It can only signal that, *based on the information that it has*, the contents are not in compliance with my budgeting policy.  Truth, and the book of record are the real world.

Greg Young discusses this in [his talk at DDDEU 2016.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s)

You can also review the Cargo DDD Sample; in particular, pay careful attention to the distinction between [Cargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo/Cargo.java) and [HandlingHistory](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/handling/HandlingHistory.java).

Aggregates are information resources; they are documents with internal consistency rules.

Comment: Who should write events into the database? There should be some aggregate in the domain model that has a related method (e.g. machine.UseBy(employee) or employee.Use(machine)). Given that `Machine` and `Employee` **are** aggregate roots (they have their own invariants and business logic in a complex net of interrelations, timeshift-feature is only one of the modules)

Comment: @EwanCoder Are the employees manually tracking when they start to work and when they finished? If that's the case then there is a high risk that the events will not be consistent (e.g. missing a finish event ) and I do not think your model should attempt to enforce consistency. It's better to just record what you have been told and ask them to correct their timesheet manually later on. In that case, I think you do not even have to care about stream versioning and you could just append to a stream not expecting any specific version.

Comment: Therefore, you probably do not even need an AR here and simply generate the events in the command handlers or use a domain service factory for the events.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your domain you must model the process of an Employee working on a machine. You can implement this using a Process manager/Saga. Let's name it `EmployeeWorkingOnAMachineSaga`. It work like that (using CQRS, you can adapt to other architectures):

- When an employee wants to start working on a machine the `EmployeeAggregate` receive the command `StartWorkingOnAMachine`.
- The `EmployeeAggregate` checks that the employee is not working on another machine and if no it raises the `EmployeeWantsToWorkOnAMachine` and change the status of the employee as `wantingToWorkOnAMachine`.
- This event is caught by the `EmployeeWorkingOnAMachineSaga` that loads the `MachineAggregate` from the repository and it sends the command `TryToUseThisMachine`; if the machine is not vacant then it rejects the command and the saga sends the `RejectWorkingOnTheMachine` command to the `EmployeeAggregate` which in turns change it's internal status (by raising an event of course)
- if the machine is vacant, it changes its internal status as `occupiedByAnEmployee` (by raising an event)
- and similar when the worker stops working on the machine.

> Now I need a way to build reports for any given Employee or any given Machine for any given period of time. For example, I want to see which machines did given employee used over period of time and for how long. Or I want to see which employees worked at this given machine for how long over period of time.

This should be implemented by `read-models` that just listen to the relevant events and build the reports that you need.

> Also, employees have a Shift that describes for how many hours a day they must work. The information from a Shift should be saved in EmployeeWorkTime aggregate in order to be consistent in a case when Shift has been changed for given Employee

Depending on how you want the system to behave you can implement it using a Saga (if you want the system to do something if the employee works more or less than it should) or as a read-model/report if you just want to see the employees that do not conform to their daily shift.

Comment: What I meant about the Shift is that it can change (begin/end times) and then all previous events will become inconsistent because they were correct only for the previous shift.

Comment: Also I created TimeSheet aggregate that persists EmployeeStartedWorkingAtTheMachine and EmployeeFinishedWorkingAtTheMachine events to the event store, all neat and comfy within single aggregate root and without any eventual consistency hell. Although I did not implemented invariants verification yet, but I plan to just check Machine and Employee aggregate from some domain service before creating/updating TimeSheet state.

Comment: Not really. Event cannot become inconsistent. They represent facts that happened. If a Shift said that worker should start at 08:00 and the worker started at 08:00 and then at a later time during the day you change the working hours to start at 09:00 it means that the worker should travel back in time? no

Comment: Design the aggregates in order to protect invariants, not to make the reports easier.

Comment: Also, try to model the aggregates and the sagas as closer to the real world as possible. Imagine that you don't have computers and only paper registries; for example every machine would have a piece of paper/registry attached on it where the employees input themselves every time they start or stop working on that machine - that is the MachineAggregate.

Comment: If my MachineAggregate would hold all records about all employees, it will be impossible to load it in a couple of years when there will be a lot of entries.

Comment: But you could create an aggregate for each working day: `WorkingDayMachineAggregate` because your invariants are limited to one day - the current day